# Flask: how do I render a webpage with a message without refreshing the webpage using Python and Flask

Tags: python, flask

I created a webpage which I linked with a database. The database comprises of 2 tables - books and loans. The webpage I created is for loans that comprises of loan id, bookid, student id, and so on. The program I am trying on this loans web page is that after typing book id, I click on a command button that searches for book id in books table, then displays book title on the loans webpage. The search happens successfully, but when book title is displayed on the loans page, the page gets refreshed, so all the data that I had typed in loan id, student id, and so on disappear. How do I send book title from app to login webpage, then display it login page without refreshing it. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance. Below is my code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

import sqlite3 as sql

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def startup():
     return render_template('Loans.html')

@app.route('/bsearch', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def bsearch():
    if request.method== "POST":
        found = "F"
        b = request.form["bid"]
      
        conn = sql.connect('library_management.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM BooksV1")
        info = cur.fetchall()

        for i in range(len(info)):
            if str(info[i][2]) == str(b):
                found = "T"
                break
        conn.close()

        if found == "T":
            return render_template('Loans.html', bname=info[i][0])
        else:
            return render_template('Loans.html', bname="Book is not found")
```

Below is my html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<b><u>Loans of RAKA library</u></b> <br>
   <br>Loan ID <br>
     <input type = "text" name = "lid" /><br><br>

<form action = "{{ url_for('bsearch') }}" method = "POST">

      Book id<br>
     <input type = "text" name = "bid" />
     <input type = "submit" value = "Search for books" /> <b>Book name: </b>  {{ bname }}
      </br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**tldr:** you need to send ajax request

As far as I know, tho. There are three ways to render page:

- sending whole html page (with jinja params like you do in your
  example code)
- sending json to client app
- sending html with ajax to replace some element's inners

First method requires whole page reload.

I try to avoid writing js code when it's possible. Here is a nice js library [htmx](https://htmx.org/), which allows you to create axaj requests with html attributes.

**main.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def startup():
    return render_template('Loans.html')


@app.route('/bsearch', methods=['POST'])
def bsearch():
    '''Returns book name html'''
    found = "T"

    try:
        book_id = int(request.form["bid"])
        book_id = book_id if book_id >= 0 else None
    except BaseException:
        book_id = None

    i = 'idk what is `i` but that does not matter anyway'
    info = {i: [
        "Book 0",
        "Book 1",
        "Book 2",
        "Book 3",
        "Book 4",
        "Book 5",
    ]}

    
    if found == "T":
        try:
            html = info[i][book_id]
        except BaseException:
            html = "Book is not found"
    else:
        html = "Book is not found"

    return html


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Loans.html:**

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form hx-post="{{ url_for('bsearch') }}" hx-target="#returned_html_goes_here">
        Book id
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="bid" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search for books" /> 
    </form>
    <b>Book name: </b> <div id="returned_html_goes_here"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

You still can manually write ajax request function, but I think that's a waste of time when you can do the same thing with html.